# how to set text size in android programatically and optionally with user

Tags: android

i want change text size property of `textView` or any text base in my app in my option dialog by user. but i don't know what method use to do this. Is there a standard for the job or not?

Comment: consider modifying http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Configuration.html#fontScale

Answer (score 2, accepted):

my class for change text size in my app:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.util.TypedValue;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class AppStyle {

    private List<ViewGroup> _Groups;
    private static float _TextSize;
    private static SharedPreferences _Prefs;

    public AppStyle(Context context, ViewGroup[] groups) {

        _Groups = new ArrayList<ViewGroup>();

        for (ViewGroup viewGroup : groups) {
         _Groups.add(viewGroup);
        }

        _Prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        setTextSize(_Prefs.getFloat("AppTextSize", 15));

        findViewInGroups();
    }

    private void findViewInGroups() {

        List<ViewGroup> Groups = new ArrayList<ViewGroup>();
        for (ViewGroup viewGroup : _Groups) {
            Groups.add(viewGroup);
        }

        _Groups.clear();
        for (ViewGroup viewGroup : Groups) {

            for (int i = 0; i < viewGroup.getChildCount(); i++) {

                if (viewGroup.getChildAt(i) instanceof ViewGroup) {
                    _Groups.add((ViewGroup) viewGroup.getChildAt(i));

                } else if (viewGroup.getChildAt(i).getId() != -1) {   //For special occasions

                    if (viewGroup.getChildAt(i) instanceof TextView) { //for TextView

                        ((TextView) viewGroup.getChildAt(i)).setTextSize(
                                TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, _TextSize);

                    } else if (viewGroup.getChildAt(i) instanceof EditText) { //for EditText

                        ((EditText) viewGroup.getChildAt(i)).setTextSize(
                                TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, _TextSize);

                    } else if (viewGroup.getChildAt(i) instanceof Button) {//for Button

                        ((Button) viewGroup.getChildAt(i)).setTextSize(
                                TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, _TextSize);

                    } else if (viewGroup.getChildAt(i) instanceof CheckBox) {//for CheckBox

                        ((CheckBox) viewGroup.getChildAt(i)).setTextSize(
                                TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, _TextSize);
                    }
                }

            }

        }
        if (_Groups.size() != 0) {

            findViewInGroups();
        } else {
            _Groups = null;
            return;
        }

    }

    public static void setTextSize(float textSize) {
        _TextSize = textSize;
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = _Prefs.edit();
        editor.putFloat("AppTextSize", textSize);
        editor.commit();
    }

}
```

But I realized that this method imposes a burden on my app.

Answer (score 0):

check this out:

```
    TextView tv=new TextView(this);

    //either:
    tv.setTextAppearance(this, R.style.textStyle1); //some style you have set up


    ///or: 
    tv.setTextSize(UserChoice);
    tv.setTextColor(R.color.myred); //some color you set up
```

Comment: it's ok, but i need to change all items on a moment and in my  app text style items is many. this method not available for me!